# using bootstrap tooltip with Vue v-for

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I want to add a bootstrap tooltip in each IMG tag that I create from Vue `v-for` but once I use `v-for` the tooltip does not work anymore.

This work without `v-for`-

```
<img src="warning.png" width="40px" heigh="40px" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!">
```

Once using `v-for`, it stopped working-

```
<img v-for="item,idx in EQP_USER_NOW" src="warning.png" width="40px" heigh="40px"
  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!" v-bind:id="idx"></img>
```

---

I just found the problem was happened after i modify the Vue `data` (EQP_USER_NOW in my case)

For example,after click the button below (modify data)
the data changed but the new `IMG` tag not worked with tootip.

```js
var vm = new Vue({

  el: '#vm',
  data: {
    EQP_USER_NOW: [{
        EQP: "A",
        USER: "Andy"
      },
      {
        EQP: "B",
        USER: "Tony"
      }
    ],
  },

  methods: {
    modify_data() {

      var vm = this
      vm.EQP_USER_NOW = [{
          EQP: "A",
          USER: "Andy"
        },
        {
          EQP: "B",
          USER: "Tony"
        },
        {
          EQP: "C",
          USER: "Max"
        }
      ]

    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.11.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
      animated: 'fade',
      placement: 'right',
      html: true
    })

  })
</script>

<body>
  <div id="vm">
    <button @Click="modify_data()">modify data</button>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">


          <img v-for="(item, idx) in EQP_USER_NOW" :key="idx" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" width="100px" heigh="100px" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!" v-bind:id="idx">



        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following small fixes-

1. `IMG` is a self-closing tag, do not close it manually.
2. When using for loop, a `key` attribute is recommended to be used.
3. It's best practice to use parenthesis to wrap multiple params like `(item, idx)`.

Finally, replace your code with this-

```
<img
  v-for="(item, idx) in EQP_USER_NOW"
  :key="idx"
  src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
  width="40px"
  heigh="40px"
  data-toggle="tooltip"
  title="Some tooltip text!"
  v-bind:id="idx"
>
```